# C++ Store latest values from a large array in a separate array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I need a way to store the latest 3 values of a large array into a separate array, but can't for the life in me figure out how to code it.

It's something in this direction:

```
int w[3] = {0, 0, 0};
int x[12] = {0, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2};

w[0] = x[i];
w[1] = x[i-1];
w[2] = x[i-2];
```

So if i = 2 , then:

```
w[0] = x[2]   = 4
w[1] = x[2-1] = 2
w[2] = x[2-2] = 0
```

The point is to use it in a code like this:

```
for (i=0; i<200; i++){

    //store x[i], x[i-1] and x[i-2] into 'w' for every value 'i'

    //compensate for undefined 'x'-values (such as x[0-1] and x[0-2] )
    //by writing '0' to corresponding 'w'
}
```

Comment: what do mean by latest 3 values? In the for loop you copy consecutive 3 values and then go to the next index and again doing th same thing.

Comment: I think he's asking to create a 2D array with index's corresponding to 'i' and pointing to a size 3 array.

if you are using a for loop and your value set is sequential why not just using such as your suggest [i],[i-1],[i-2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update according to:

```
w[2] = w[1];
w[1] = w[0];
w[0] = x[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
w[0] = 0;
w[1] = 0;
w[2] = 0;
w[0] = x[i];
if （i>=1）
{
   w[1] = x[i-1] ;
}
if ( i>= 2)
{
   w[2] = x[i-2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the size of your large array is 200-

```
    s = 0;
    for (l = 200 ; l > 197 ; l--) {
        x[s] = w[l];
        s++;
    }
```